# Sending JSON array using PHP to Android Volley

Tags: php, android, mysql, json, android-volley

I am sending an array of data from MySQL query, and I am using json_encode to do that:

```
public function getFriends($id){
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT uid, name, email
                        FROM users
                        RIGHT JOIN friendships 
                        ON friendid2 = uid")        or die (mysql_error());

$jsonData = '{"tag":"friends",error":"false",';
$jsonData .= '"friends":[';

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $i++;
    $id = $row["uid"];
    $name = $row["name"];
    $email = $row["email"];
    $jsonData .= '{"id":"'.$id.'","name":"'.$name.'","email":"'.$email.'"},';
}

$jsonData = chop($jsonData, ",");
$jsonData .= ']}';
echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

In the Android LogCat, when I'm creating JSON object I see this:

```
 org.json.JSONException: Value {"tag":"friends",error":"false","friends":[{"id":"4","name":"GrubyJohny2","email":"gruby@gmail.com"},{"id":"243000000","name":"Wariacik","email":"karol@wp.com"}]} of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject
```

Can anyone tell me what am I doing wrong ? Becouse I searched bounch of toutorials and I think my json syntax is correct.

The way I am receiving message from server:

```
private void getFriendships(final String id) {

    String tag_string_req = "req_friendships";
    pDialog.setMessage("Sending Request for list of friends");
    showDialog();
    final String TAG = "List of friends request";
    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, AppConfig.URL_REGISTER, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Friendship request Response: " + response.toString());
            hideDialog();
            try {

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response); 
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

                if (!error) {

                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Friends uploaded", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } else {

                    String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "List of friends request Error: " + error.toString());

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            hideDialog();

        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("tag", "friends");
            params.put("sender", id);

            return params;
        }

    };

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: why dont you use `json_encode` http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: please add your Java code. i think you are using this line `JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);` that might cause the problem

Answer (score 0):

```
"friends",error":"false"
```

The `error` key needs quotes on both sides.

You can copy / paste the JSON in many free services, such as [jsonlint.org](http://jsonlint.org/) that will parse your string for you and tell you if and where the errors are.

As @Noman pointed out in the comments, you can also just build out the entirety of the data as a PHP array (and not just portions of it), and then simply `json_encode` all of it at the very end:

```
$jsonData = array(
    'tag' => 'friends',
    'error' => 'false',
    'friends' => array(),
);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $jsonData['friends'][] = array(
        'id'    => $row['uid'],
        'name'  => $row['name'],
        'email' => $row['email'],
    );
}

echo json_encode($jsonData);
```

Also, it should be noted that [`mysql_query`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) as well as all `mysql_*` functions are now *deprecated*.  You should not write new code that uses these functions.  Instead you should learn to use either [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) extensions for communicating with your database.

Comment: You'll need to update your question with how you're trying to convert the string you're getting to JSON from the Android app. If the JSON from the PHP is valid, then in your case PHP is not the problem.

Comment: I updated my question like you wanted. I pasted your code but in LogCat I got:

 <b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in <b>/android_api/include/DB_Functions.php</b> on line <b>79</b><br />

79'th line is:
$jsonData = [

Comment: You're probably on a version of PHP before the short array syntax was introduced. I'll update the answer to not use it.

Comment: No prob, glad to help